# How to export models from libraries in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I created an Angular library, but I want to export a Model which my application can use.  How can I do that ?

For example :

**my-library**

library-model.ts

```js
export class LibraryModel{
  //some model data
}
```

my-library.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

//some imports    

@Component( {
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...',
    styleUrls: [...]
} )
export class MyLibraryComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() libInputData: LibraryModel;

    // some other codes
}
```

my-library.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { MyLibraryComponent} from './my-library.component';
import { LibraryModel} from './library-model';

@NgModule( {
    declarations: [MyLibraryComponent, LibraryModel],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    exports: [MyLibraryComponent, LibraryModel]
} )
export class MyLibraryModule { }
```

public_api.ts

```js
export * from './lib/my-library.service';
export * from './lib/my-library.component';
export * from './lib/my-library.module';
export * from './lib/library-model';
```

**my-app**

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LibraryModel } from 'my-library';

@Component({
  selector: 'grc-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-application';

  libraryModel : LibraryModel ;

  initializeData() {

     //initialize and set data for libraryModel 

  }
}
```

app.component.html

```js
<my-lib-component libInputData="libraryModel" ></my-lib-component>
```

However with this set-up, I get a "Can't export value LibraryModel ..." error during build of the library.
I wanted to use the LibraryModel so I can easily pass the data in app.component.html.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: show the `LibraryData` component

Comment: And what is your `LibraryData `, I do not get it ?

Comment: Also, LibraryModel is not a declarable nor a module, so it has nothing to do in the exports of your library module. It's just a class, unrelated to angular.

Comment: sorry, typo ... LibraryData -> LibraryModel ... corrected detail of question.

Answer (score 4):

**You cannot declare / export it**, it is a model, simple **non-angular class** not a `component`, remove it from both arrays (`declarations` & `exports`). It is already exported by **`export class LibraryModel`**.

> Don't declare the following:
>
> - A class that's already declared in another NgModule
> - An array of directives imported from another package. For example,    don't declare FORMS_DIRECTIVES from @angular/forms
> - NgModule classes
> - Service classes
> - Non-Angular classes and objects, such as strings, numbers, functions,    entity models, configurations, business logic, and
>     helper classes

**[MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)**

**[Don't declare (Official doc)](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#declarable)**.

Comment: To clarify the answer, you do need to add it to the public_api.ts as the op did.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove '`LibraryModel`' from your declarations and exports in `my-library.module.ts`
2. Make sure it is exported in `public_api.ts`
3. Make sure the library import URLs are right in your component.

E.g.

**Right**: `import { MenuItemsModel } from 'dist/ngx-circular-menu';`

**Wrong**: `import { MenuItemsModel } from 'dist/ngx-circular-menu/lib/menu-items.model';`

That's it!